# R - Rank Largest to Smallest

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I am using `Rank()` to assign a rank value to a dataframe, however I need the rank to be 1 = Highest and not 1 = Lowest.

Answer (score 45):

If you want to get the rank of `x` from the largest to the smallest, do

```
rank(-x)
```

Answer (score 11):

Or you could use :

```
> x = c(1,2,3,4,5)
> rank(desc(x))
[1] 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 9):

Also:

```
> x = 1:10
> order(-x)
 [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Answer (score 3):

While `rank(-x)` will certainly work for numeric and logical vectors, it won't work on character vectors, as those cannot be negated. Instead, a solution which work on all types of vectors:

`rank(-rank(x))`

Answer (score 1):

The following would do it:

```
order(x, decreasing=TRUE)
```

Comment: I believe order sorts the data, ranking gives a numerical number.

Comment: The `order()` function will produce a different result than the `rank()` function so this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
x[order(-x)]
```

you will get

```
6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score -1):

```
ascending_order=arrange[order(arrange)]
Rank_values=rank(ascending_order)
```