# Drop lines in a long dataset by group, based on some condition

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this df:

```
library(lubridate)

Date <- c("2020-10-01", "2020-10-02", "2020-10-03", "2020-10-04", 
          "2020-10-01", "2020-10-02", "2020-10-03", "2020-10-04",
          "2020-10-01", "2020-10-02", "2020-10-03", "2020-10-04")
Date <- as_date(Date)

Country <- c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
             "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico",
             "Japan", "Japan", "Japan","Japan")

Value_A <- c(0,40,0,0,25,29,34,0,20,25,27,0)

df<- data.frame(Date, Country, Value_A)
```

```
view(df)

    Date      Country Value_A
   <date>     <chr>     <dbl>
 1 2020-10-01 USA           0
 2 2020-10-02 USA          40
 3 2020-10-03 USA           0
 4 2020-10-04 USA           0
 5 2020-10-01 Mexico       25
 6 2020-10-02 Mexico       29
 7 2020-10-03 Mexico       34
 8 2020-10-04 Mexico        0
 9 2020-10-01 Japan        20
10 2020-10-02 Japan        25
11 2020-10-03 Japan        27
12 2020-10-04 Japan         0
```

**I'm trying to drop the rows containing zeros, but only if these zeros are in the last two rows of each group of the Country column. So the result would be:**

```
   Date      Country Value_A
   <date>     <chr>     <dbl>
 1 2020-10-01 USA           0
 2 2020-10-02 USA          40
 5 2020-10-01 Mexico       25
 6 2020-10-02 Mexico       29
 7 2020-10-03 Mexico       34
 9 2020-10-01 Japan        20
10 2020-10-02 Japan        25
11 2020-10-03 Japan        27
```

I appreciate it if someone can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the **`tidyverse`** package to do a few manipulations to get the result. We `group_by` Country, and sort descending by `Date`. After that, we generate `row_number`s. Finally, we filter based on the condition you described:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    group_by(Country) %>%
    arrange(desc(Date)) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    filter(!(Value_A == 0 & rn <= 2))

#   Date       Country Value_A    rn
# 1 2020-10-03 Mexico       34     2
# 2 2020-10-03 Japan        27     2
# 3 2020-10-02 USA          40     3
# 4 2020-10-02 Mexico       29     3
# 5 2020-10-02 Japan        25     3
# 6 2020-10-01 USA           0     4
# 7 2020-10-01 Mexico       25     4
# 8 2020-10-01 Japan        20     4
```

Another [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43388410/5619526) would be to use `rank(desc(Date))`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(Country) %>%
    mutate(rank_date = rank(desc(Date))) %>%
    filter(!(rank_date <= 2 & Value_A == 0))

#   Date       Country Value_A rank_date
# 1 2020-10-01 USA           0         4
# 2 2020-10-02 USA          40         3
# 3 2020-10-01 Mexico       25         4
# 4 2020-10-02 Mexico       29         3
# 5 2020-10-03 Mexico       34         2
# 6 2020-10-01 Japan        20         4
# 7 2020-10-02 Japan        25         3
# 8 2020-10-03 Japan        27         2
```